# How to send text to the textarea as per the html through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I want to click and send text within a textbox but not able to find the element.

This is the html I want to click and send text-

```
<form class="addComment expand" data-id="9656414">
<img 
src="https://ctl.s6img.com/society6/img/g2taHIrokQ01R_67jS8ulaWI2wk/h_150,w_150/users/avatar/~artwork/s6-original-art-uploads/society6/uploads/u/sul97/avatar_asset/d837ee10016843a3bba9ae3310cc338d" width="25" height="25">
                                <textarea placeholder="Add a comment..." data-button="9656414"></textarea>
                                <button id="b9656414">Comment</button>
                            </form>
```

My code:-

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('add').click()
comments = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form[2]")
comments.click()
comments.send_keys("Awesome Art")
```

I can click but cant type text on it. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you wants to send text on textarea ?

Comment: Why do you want to click textarea? What is the point? Do you need to click something to expand form with textarea? Describe the sequence of actions you want your script to perform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the desired element is a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form.addComment.expand textarea[placeholder^='Add a comment']"))).send_keys("Awesome Art")
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@class='addComment expand']//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'Add a comment')]"))).send_keys("Awesome Art")
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: XPath worked! but can you also show the path of clicking button?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to type text on Text Area, You need to locate text area:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@data-button='9656414']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to click and send text to the `form` itself, not to textarea. Here how you can locate textarea and button inside `form`.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[class='addComment expand'] textarea").send_keys("Awesome Art")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[class='addComment expand'] button").click()
```